# Yeson.json.object is applied to too many arguments

Tags: haskell, yesod, classy-prelude

```
import Yesod
import Data.Text

data App = App

instance Yesod App

mkYesod "App" [parseRoutes|
               / Home GET
               |]

getHome :: String -> Handler Value
getHome  =  object ["name" .= ("Adam"::Text)]

main = warpDebug 2012 App
```

throws error as,

```
 Couldn't match expected type ‘String -> Handler Value’
                with actual type ‘Value’
    Possible cause: ‘object’ is applied to too many arguments
    In the expression: object ["name" .= ("Adam" :: Text)]
    In an equation for ‘getHome’:
        getHome = object ["name" .= ("Adam" :: Text)]
```

`object` is not in scope in prelude. Which package/module defines this? Why doesn't it take the key-value pair in the above case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `object` is not in scope in prelude. Which package/module defines this?

[Yesod.Json](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-json-1.1.0/docs/Yesod-Json.html#v:object)

> Why doesn't it take the key-value pair in the above case?

It takes the key value pair just fine. The error message is telling you that `object` gives you a `Value`, but you declared `getHome` to be of type `String -> Handler Value`, not `Value`.

The "possible cause" seems to just be misleading in this case.

Comment: I tried changing the type. It gave this error -    Couldn't match expected type ‘HandlerT App IO res0’
                with actual type ‘Value’
. `getHome` is my HTTP GET handler that returns a json response. How can i wrap the `Value` type with `Handler` instead of changing the type?